# Is it possible in liferay to make an ajax call independent of a portlet?

Tags: ajax, liferay, liferay-6

I would like to make an ajax call from javascript code (to check if the user session is still active). I would like my code to be independent of any portlet, and hence would like to build the url in javascript, without having to rely on a portlet id.

Is this possible within the MVCPortlet framework ? If not, are there alternatives ?

**Edit below this line.**

I am aware of liferay's mechanisms for session management, and I actually have set an automatic extension of the session. But two of my users have lost thier long input because the session expired despite this mechanism (I believe they interrupted their work, and their computer went to sleep...).

I would like to avoid such a situation by checking if a session is still active before I submit an input from certain forms. The way I do it is prepend the submit with an ajax call which I detail below.

My true question is : **how do I remove the reliance on portletId in that code so that I don't need to change every portlet in which I want to implement this mechanism.**

I do it today with the following javascript function:

```
Liferay.provide(window, "bb_checkSession",
    function (sessionId, portletId, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        var A = AUI();
        var resourceUrl = Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();
        resourceUrl.setResourceId("CHECK_SESSION");
        resourceUrl.setPortletId(portletId);
        A.io.request(resourceUrl.toString(), {
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            on: {
                success: function () {
                    var responseData = A.JSON.parse(this.get('responseData'));
                    if (responseData == null || sessionId != responseData.sessionId) {
                        if (failureCallback) failureCallback();
                    } else {
                        if (successCallback) successCallback();
                    }
                },
                failure: function () {
                    if (failureCallback) failureCallback();
                }
            }
        });
    },
    ['aui-io', 'liferay-portlet-url']
);
```

and in my portlet, I handle the call as follows

```
public void checkSession(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException {

    PortletSession session = resourceRequest.getPortletSession();

    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    resourceResponse.setContentType("text/javascript");
    jsonObject.put("sessionId", session.getId());
    resourceResponse.getWriter().write(jsonObject.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vikas, Olaf, for your quick reactions which are useful, but don't really solve my issue. I am editing my post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved through [Jquery](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-mint.htm). If in your `web.xml` you have defined `session-timeout` as 15 mins, then at 14th minute a lightbox will appear which will ask User if he wishes to continue the session or logout.

If User wishes to continue session, then `/c/portal/extend_session` is called(Ajax) else `/c/portal/logout` is called.

Below code works independent of any type of portlet. You need to place this code in your JSP/Facelets page.

```
<script src="/static-files/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/static-files/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/static-files/scripts/jquery.idletimer.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/static-files/scripts/jquery.idletimeout.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="/static-files/css/jquery-ui-rev.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var $j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function()
        {

    $j("#dialog").attr("style","visibility:visible");
    var titletext=$j(this).attr('title');
    $j("#dialog").bind("contextmenu",function(event)
            {   return false; })

// setup the dialog
$j("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
    'Yes, Continue': function()
    {

        $j.ajax({
              url: '/c/portal/extend_session',
              cache: false,
              success: function() {
                $j('div#dialog').dialog('close');
              }
            });

        $j(document).attr('title',titletext);
        },
        'No, Log out': function(){

            $j.idleTimeout.options.onTimeout.call($j.post('/c/portal/logout',function()
                {}))
        }
    }

});

// cache a reference to the countdown element so we don't have to query the DOM for it on each ping.
var $jcountdown = $j("#dialog-countdown");

// start the idle timer plugint
$j.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
    idleAfter: 840,   // 14 mins

    onTimeout: function(){
        window.location.replace("/c/portal/logout");
    },
    onIdle: function(){
        $j(document).attr('title', 'Warning! Due to inactivity, your session is about to expire.');
        $j(this).dialog("open");


    },
    onCountdown: function(counter){
        $jcountdown.html(counter); // update the counter
    }
});
        });
</script>

<!-- dialog window markup -->
<div id="dialog" title="Your session is about to expire!" style="visibility:hidden">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        You will be logged out in <span id="dialog-countdown" style="font-weight:bold;whitespace:nowrap"></span> seconds.
    </p>

    <p>Do you wish to continue your session?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vikas V gave you some code that you can use - there are two aspects of your question that don't really match my perception...

1. Liferay already has such a mechanism - e.g. log in to your portal and let it sit for 30 minutes (or configure the timeout to be earlier) and you'll see that you get a warning message, followed by a "you have been logged out" message if you don't click "extend session". in 6.1 this is even working through multiple open tabs (I believe it's using js-cookies to contain a timestamp, so that all tabs timeout at the same time)
2. if you make a request to the server in order to check if the session is still active, you risk extending the session - e.g. just checking for the session being alive might extend it eternally

Thus, my recommendation is to either hook into Liferay's mechanism (edit your question or comment here if you need hints where to find it, I'd have to look it up) or to use your own fully client side implementation. If you opt for your own implementation (e.g. like Vikas V suggested) , keep in mind that you might have multiple tabs open and you wouldn't want to be logged out by a stale tab that you forgot about in the background.